# MySQL - Find Records in Table A that exist as a Substring in Table B

Tags: sql, mysql

I am tasked with cleaning up our stale DNS entries. I first captured all DNS requests for a period of time. I then exported a list of all DNS entries in our zone.

The DNS requests that were captured have a FQDN (server.domain.com)

The DNS entries that were exported have just a short name (server)

The goal is to find all DNS entries that exist, that do NOT show up in the capture.

This will tell me which entries are stale and can probably be deleted.

I created 2 tables in MySql (dns_entries and dns_scan)

I imported the data to the respective tables, with only 1 column in each called (record).

```
Sample Data for Table 1 (dns_entries)
server1
server2
server3
server4
server5
server6
```

```
Sample Data for Table 2 (dns_scan)
server1.domain.com
server2.domain.com
server3.domain.com
server4.domain.com
```

I crafted what I thought was a good query to find all records in Table A (dns_entries) that do not exist as a substring in Table B (dns_scan). Table B (dns_scan) has FQDN data (server.domain.com) while Table A (dns_entries) only has the short name (server)

```
SELECT a.record
FROM dns_entries a
LEFT JOIN dns_scan b
ON b.record NOT LIKE concat(a.record, '%')
```

Im not sure if the query is supposed to work, but they run for hours on end with no result.

Ideally, with the above query, i should get a return of "server5" and "server6" as this data doesnt exist in Table 2 at all.

Can someone confirm if the above query will perform what I need?

I feel like im very close but missing something stupid.

Comment: Your join logic is not correct as it will match all rows from the right table that do not contain the substring to a row in a left table. See the answers to the duplicate question on how to get rows that are not in another table

Comment: This ended up working for me. 

SELECT *
FROM tablea a
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
FROM tableb b 
WHERE b.record LIKE concat(a.record, '%'));